# How to Identify a Convolution in Fourier Transform, specifically $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^2+1}$

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

As a part of an exercize in **Fourier transforms** I came across this integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^2+1}
\end{equation}
I don't know why, but I felt that this has to be a convolution of two functions. Which two - I didn't have a clue.

According to the answer we have to define a function g(x):
$g(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$

Then is says "*we can now **easily** identify that*:"
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{f(y)}{(x-y)^2+1} = f*g(x)
\end{equation}
where $f*g$ is the convolution of f and g.

Knowing that the definition of a convolution is:
\begin{equation}
(f*g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-y)g(y)dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)g(x-y)dy
\end{equation}
...I have 3 questions:

1. How can we "*easily*" see that the first function is a convolution?
2. How do you identify a convolution generally?
3. What's the method you experienced people use to identify and define the function with which we convolute f with (like g(x) in this case)?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: What is $g(x-y)$?

Comment: I always identify convolutions by  asking the following: which function is counted "forward," i.e., $f(y)$, and which one "backward," i.e., $g(x - y)$? If I see a special composition, I can identify parts of the convolution.

Comment: @kevinkayaks this helped my very much! Thanks!